# How can I find the Metasploit modules/exploits folder?

Tags: linux, security, exploit, metasploit

I need to go to Metasploit exploits directory in order to download new exploit written by some guy so I need to find **metasploit-framework/modules/exploits** directory.

I trying to see if the folder at least exists, so I type:

```
ls /usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/
```

But I'm getting ***No such directory*** error, because there is no **metasploit-framework** directory in ***/usr/share***.

You may think I didn't install msf properly, but I used an official way of installing from github msf repository. I thought it's installation fault too until I tried to watch ***/opt/metasploit-framework*** folder and seems like all files okay there. It's definitely my fault because I got same result on both Ubuntu and Debian servers, but I can't understand what am I doing wrong.

```
ls /opt/metasploit-framework
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu the exploit scripts are in this folder. I followed the symlinks from **/usr/bin/msfconsole**.

```
/opt/metasploit-framework/embedded/framework/modules
```

On Termux in this one.

```
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/opt/metasploit-framework
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost all of your interaction with Metasploit will be through its many modules, which it looks for in two locations. The first is the primary module store under /usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/ and the second, which is where you will store custom modules, is under your home directory at ~/.msf4/modules/.

```
root@kali:~# ls /usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/
auxiliary  encoders  exploits  nops  payloads  post
```

All Metasploit modules are organized into separate directories, according to their purpose. A basic overview of the various types of Metasploit modules is shown below.

Please  Replay with your metasploit version